# Return an integer number for a given byte[16] array and bit range between 1 and 128. Big endian

Tags: java, bit, mifare

I need to retrieve an integer number for the selected bit range (1-128) of a Mifare Classic 1k block (16 byte array). The number is represented binary with Big Endian.

I know how to do it manually with bitwise operations for a given range but i'm not able to make a method to handle it. I have tried to use java.util.BitSet also but it works with little-endian representation.

Actual code:

```
private int byteToInt(byte[] payload, int from, int to) {
    BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(payload);
    byte[] array = bitSet.get(from,to).toByteArray();
    if(array.length == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return new BigInteger(array).intValue();
}
```

The byte array on the BigInteger constructor is assumed to be big-endian byte-ordered while BitSet.toByteArray() returns a little-endian byte array

Comment: Could you please post the code for your best attempt. Thanks

Comment: The constructor of `BigInteger` already accepts a byte array in big-endian representation. So what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the byte array into different endianness. Look here on how to convert little to big endian 
[Converting Little Endian to Big Endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842828/converting-little-endian-to-big-endian)

and here for the other diection

[Java - Convert Big-Endian to Little-Endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693406/java-convert-big-endian-to-little-endian)

Answer (score -1):

Something like this for big indane:-

```
int output = 0;
for (int index=0; index < size; index++)
{
    output = output | (arrary[index] << index);
}
```

Comment: output |= (arrary[index] << index);

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer. BigInteger output = BigInteger.valueOf(0); in loop output = output.or(arrary[index] << (index*8)); guessing code you did. If not please share for others benefit